# SQL Fetch the record closest to integer in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables. I'm tying to get the record(person) that has the most wins first. If 2 people have the same amount of wins then I need the person that is closest to the Total Points. In this scenario tim should be the record displayed.
Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Table 1

```
|____Week____|____Name____|____Wins____|___TotalPoint___|
|            |            |            |                |
|__ Week1 ___|___ bob ____|____ 5 _____|______ 20 ______|
|            |            |            |                |
|__ Week1 ___|___ sam ____|____ 8 _____|______ 12 ______|
|            |            |            |                | 
|__ Week1 ___|___ tim_____|____ 8 _____|______ 45 ______|
|            |            |            |                | 
|__ Week1 ___|___ dan_____|____ 3 _____|______ 31 ______|
|            |            |            |                | 
|__ Week1 ___|___ rob_____|____ 1 _____|______ 50 ______|
```

Table 2

```
|____Week____|___TotalPoint___|
|            |                |
|__ Week1 ___|______ 40 ______|
```

Comment: Please tell us which version of SQL you are using.

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work on SQL Server:

```
SELECT TOP 1 t1.*
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t1.Week = t2.Week
ORDER BY
    t1.Wins DESC,
    ABS(t1.TotalPoint - t2.TotalPoint);
```

Comment: I'm using sql studio 2012